# How to start faye automatically using daemon-controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, faye

I am trying to run faye automatically using gem daemon_controller.
**My Class**

```
require "daemon_controller" 
class FayeDaemon
def initialize
  @controller = DaemonController.new(
      :identifier    => 'Faye server',
      :start_command => "rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production",
      :ping_command  => [:tcp , 'localhost', 9292],
      :log_file      => 'log/faye.log',
      :pid_file      => 'tmp/pids/faye.pid',
      :start_timeout => 5
   )
end    

  def start
  @controller.start
  end
end
```

**Function**  I  use as before_filter in ApplicationController

```
 def start_faye
 fayes = FayeDaemon.new
 fayes.start
 end
```

as a result faye doesn't run with error

DaemonController::StartTimeout (Daemon 'Faye server' didn't daemonize in time.)

when  fayes.start is called.

what i did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to use foreman instead of deamon_controller, you can find good introduction [here](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html). Just install gem, create 'Procfile' in your rails root directory. and create two jobs, one for server and other for Faye, it could look like this:

```
web:    bundle exec rails server webrick -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
faye:   bundle exec rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production
```

and start foreman with

```
foreman start
```